# How to install Software package on windows vps?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, vps

I have installed 3 vps on my windows machine. now i want different software on every vps. so do i install all software on main machine on which i installed vps or should i login in all vps one by one and install software separately? is there any other way by which i install all software on main server machine and allocate them to VPS?

thank you...

Comment: 1) Ensure the installers are accessible to your VPS 2) Remote desktop into your VPS 3) Run the aforementioned installers 4) Profit!

Comment: I fear that this is incoherent, as it stands.  Typically one runs installers on whatever machine they are installing software on; there is no procedure, nor is any warranted.  If you encounter some problem besides extreme disorientation, feel free to ask about it.

Answer (score 3):

From the viewpoint of installing software, a virtual machine is just like the real thing, you need to install software from inside the virtual machine.